# Autosign Documents using DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I currently have a Web application that generates multiple contracts in PDF format. The requirement is to get the customer e-signatures on these contracts. I do not want to send the documents to the customer to e-sign through DocuSign, rather direct them to DocuSign, have them e-sign on DocuSign, retrieve the e-signature and then silently add the signatures on multiple PDF's. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign's eSignature API doesn't support robo-signing. Signatures must be applied by a user taking action - this process cannot be automated.