# DocusignAPI with autosign envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

I have ready to use the flow of creating templates and envelopes:

1. User creating own template
2. By using the sender view user can edit fields/tabs
3. When the action is called application generates an envelope with the recipient's data (2x signs)

My question is about an automatic way of signing the envelopes. Is there any possibility of creating auto-sign envelopes?  ("owner" has already signed the envelope for sending to multiple recipients?)

(I'm not sure if this is still relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/58648934/4428956 ?)

I want to know if 1 user is able to prepare ready-to-use template with automatic signature generated in flight without his participation. The only action for the user will take, will be selecting recipients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the post you linked is still correct. DocuSign does not support robo-signing. All signers must manually open and sign the envelope.